# Не могу получить координаты html элемента =(

Tags: javascript

Пытался получить координаты **Block-1** и прокрутить страницу до него, но я что-то сделал не так =(
Как получить координаты html элемента **Block-1** и прокрутить страницу до него

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('.Block-1');
let coords = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
elem.style.top = coords.bottom + 'px';


window.scrollTo({
    top: elem,
    behavior: "smooth"
});
```

```css
.Block-1{
margin-top:500px;
border:1px solid black;
font-size:30px;
padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "Block-1"> 

Прокрутка

</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте вместо этого [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: Он намного гибче, можно настроить плавную прокрутку и не нужно знать координаты элемента и много другого) Если не разберётесь, дайте знать выставлю более развёрнутый вариант как ответ

Comment: В моём случае это не сработает, я использую код в Wordpress в файле  search.php, который выдает результаты поиска. Долго искал решение, но остановился на window.scrollTo. Мне бы получить координаты html элемента *Block-1* =(

Comment: Чет я туплю, плс можно пример Element.scrollIntoView()  с моим кодом =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример с [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView):

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('.Block-1');

elem.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: "smooth"
});
```

```css
.Block-1 {
  margin-top: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Block-1">

  Прокрутка

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для `scrollTo`, нужно передавать число, а не DOM элемент https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

В данном случае, как я понимаю, вы уже получили все нужные значения в `coords`, а именно `coords.top`

```
window.scrollTo({
    top: top: coords.top,
    behavior: "smooth"
});
```

Comment: Не поможет. `getBoundingClientRect` возвращает положение относительно viewport'а, а значит если уже проскроллено куда-то, получится фигня.

Comment: А что тогда использовать? elem.scrollIntoView ?